# CameraKit compile fail

Tags: java, android, api, github, camera

Hi I am trying to import CameraKit from this github in my project:

https://github.com/wonderkiln/CameraKit-Android

But then I compile my app after adding this library I press Sync gradle and no error is showing in Android Studio Logcat, but if I try to run it the my emulator, I get this error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Dex writing phase: classes.dex has too many IDs. Try using multi-dex","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformJackWithJackForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack compilation exception

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5 mins 15.228 secs

Error:Dex writing phase: classes.dex has too many IDs. Try using multi-dex
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack compilation exception
```

My App gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jacklas.fitnessm8"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 100131
        versionName "1.0A(131)"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize '4096m'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.11.0'

    // retrofit, gson, jxjava
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'

    compile 'br.com.liveo:navigationdrawer-material:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.0.2'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

So my question is how do it fix it without using "multiDexEnabled true" can I import the github to my project so it doesn't have to compile it from ?:

compile 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.11.0'

Comment: Just use "multiDexEnabled  = true"  or Instead of using whole library use selected module which is required in your app.

Comment: the problem is that the multiDex makes my app with more errors, that I cant fix :(

Comment: What Emulator are you using?

Comment: I use the Android Emulator build in Android Studio 3 - API 27